# NodeJS Read File data when it changes

Tags: node.js

I have a cron-job added in my nodejs application. It creates/update a json file every 10 min. I have a express rest api that reads from the json file and show the data. Everything works fine so far. Now when corn-job updates the json file i can see the updated data in json file but if i make a request to my api it shows the old data. How can i get the latest data from my json file when it changes.?

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("data.json");
let jsonData = Object.fromEntries(JSON.parse(rawdata));

exports.getLogData = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).send({jsonData});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
};
```

This is how i'm reading the data from json file and posting it. Its showing the data but when the data changes in the data.json file via node-corn, this jsonData is not updating.

Comment: please share your code so that we can understand how you are making the request and know where the problem is

Comment: You would probably want to use something like this: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener and then reread the file

Comment: You are reading the json file only once. You should watch the changes or read again the file on each request.

Comment: Thanks ```fs.watch()``` solves this issue for me.